# Событие захвата другого окна

Tags: c#, hook

Как можно отследить событие, при котором юзер перетаскивает окно другого приложения, при этим получать хендлер этого окна (в идеале сразу с самим процессом / именем процесса)?

В итоге должно получиться примерно это https://youtu.be/YHtz9Dkalfo?t=190

После гугления нашёл это https://stackoverflow.com/q/20690078/12888024

Но не уверен, что это то, что мне нужно

Comment: Не уверены? А вы попробуйте.

Comment: @aepot я вижу подпись на движение мыши, а где остальное?) Мне нужен не факт движения мыши, а факт перетаскивания окна и определение этого окна

Comment: Вы не можете узнать, началось ли перетаскивание окна, потому что это за пределами ответственности операционной системы, и находится внутри кода приложения. Вы можете только предположить, что юзер зажал кнопку мыши на заголовке окна и потащил его, а по изменению координат мыши догадаться, куда. Но я могу ошибаться, и возможно есть способ проще и надежнее.

Comment: @aepot в LG OnScreen Control как-то же реализовали эту технологию, мне нужно то же самое https://youtu.be/YHtz9Dkalfo?t=190